# Does thermodynamics predict the effect of spontaneous emission (QED)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, quantum-electrodynamics

Could one say that spontaneous emission is expected from thermodynamics, as a isolated atom needs a relaxation process to the ground state to reach equilibrium at low temperatures?

Comment: Though not directly, Einstein derived the blackbody spectrum by assuming quantised matter and radiation being in thermal equilibrium. The only way he could get results matching Planck’s distribution was by having two mechanisms. Spontaneous and stimulated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I think not.

Firstly, I'm not sure what it even means for an isolated atom to have a low temperature (or any temperature at all) - temperature is a property of a thermodynamically large systems. It does make sense for an individual atom to be in contact with a *reservoir* at low temperature, which is presumably what you mean.

In such a case, the Boltzmann distribution would predict that the probability that the atom is in a state with energy $E$ is given by $e^{-E/kT}/Z(T)$, where $Z(t) = \displaystyle\sum_i e^{-E_i/kT}$ is the partition function.  As $T\rightarrow 0$, the probability that the atom is in its ground state approaches $1$.

---

However, this argument suffers from a fatal flaw - it assumes that the atom can freely exhange energy with the reservoir.  This is, after all, what it *means* for two systems to be in thermal contact.  However, it is possible in principle that there is no way for the reservoir to accept precisely the right amount of energy for the atom to decay into its ground state.

As a simple model, one could imagine a reservoir of quantum harmonic oscillators with frequency $\omega$.  Letting the temperature of the reservoir be $T=0$, we see that the oscillators are all in their ground states.

Now we put this reservoir in contact with a single oscillator with frequency $\omega' = \omega/2$ which happens to be in its first excited state.  I put the word contact in quotes because it's easy to see that there is no way for the system of higher-frequency oscillators to accept a parcel of energy equal to $\hbar \omega' = \hbar\omega/2$, since the smallest amount of energy the reservoir could accept would be $\hbar\omega$.  As a result, this configuration would be stable despite the fact that the low-frequency oscillator is not in its ground state.

---

Now, in practice such a system/reservoir may be impossible to realize due to stray EM radiation, the influence of phonons, etc.  The point remains, however, that it is *in principle* possible to have a system and a reservoir which are such that there is no physical route by which the system can reach its ground state.  The **assumption** that such a route exists is baked into much of standard thermodynamics and statistical physics via the definition of thermal contact, and so the subsequent *prediction* of said route would be circular.

Comment: I agree with what you say.. But I don't think this contradicts what I wanted to do. I totally get your point, when you say "in principle possible to have a system and a reservoir which are such that there is no physical route by which the system can reach its ground state". I didn't want to make a rigorous argument to rule this out. I much more wanted to make a consistency argument, along the lines of:

Comment: "As expected from the notion of thermal equilibrium in classical thermodynamics, which was established long before the advent of QM, it is expected that matter should equilibrate with an external reservoir. Einstein therefore postulated that there should be a relaxation process, independent from the external radiation field. The exact dynamics of this process can only be fully understood when quantizing not just the atom itself, but also the fields." in my bachelors thesis and wanted to make sure it's not total nonsense.

Comment: "It does make sense for an individual atom to be in contact with a reservoir at low temperature, which is presumably what you mean." Exactly. It's more like a thought experiment to understand the need for this spontaneous emission without doing QED, a road I don't want to go down.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum I don't think that's the case, though.  If you can use thermodynamics/statistical physics to argue for spontaneous emission, then why can't I use it to argue for e.g. the decay of an electron into two photons?  The argument would be morally the same - the entropy of the macrostate characterized by two photons and no electrons is larger than the entropy of the macrostate characterized by no photons and one electron.  Whether electrons actually *do* decay is beyond the scope of thermodynamics, and the same is true of spontaneous emission.

Comment: Interesting point. Hm... I still think that the "contradiction" between the atom being able to stay in the excited state forever according to normal QM and the thermodynamic understanding of everything approaching a ground state of some sort eventually hints one to expect that there is "some other process". Accepting this hint one could then argue that giving off one photon would be the easiest way to equilibrate and even conserve the mass..

Comment: As you pointed out this is not really a contradiciton though.. More like something odd. But it may serve as a somewhat handwavy motivation to introduce the spontaneous emission term I think.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum But mass isn't conserved.  Everything I said for the electron holds for e.g. the $\pi^0$, but the $\pi^0$ *does* decay into two photons while the electron does not. My perspective on this matter is that there's nothing wrong with postulating the existence of a spontaneous decay mechanism for excited atoms, but justifying it based on thermodynamics is a non-sequitur.

Comment: Okay, you are right, my last sentence "giving off one photon would be the easiest way to equilibrate and even conserve the mass.. " is very weak and not really based on anything but the result I want. What I will do now is to keep the thermodynamic consistency reasoning to establish that there probably must be "some other process", in order to avoid atoms being in an excited state forever, and then introduce the concept of spontaneous emission as a postulate/result from QED. I think this is more satisfying than just saying we postulate it without the reader seeing any need for it.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum It's worth bearing in mind that there is nothing wrong whatsoever with not having a rigorous justification for a postulate - that's why it's called a postulate in the first place.  What one typically does is say, "if we **assume** [postulate], then what would we expect to see?" If the results match our observations, then that can provide *a posteriori* justification.  In this case, **if** a decay mechanism exists, **then** what we would expect to see based on statistical physics and QM does indeed match our experience.

Comment: Thank you for your fruitful input!